Lynch-esque film with a Gold motif
I'm pretty sure it was released in the last decade or so. It's got a David Lynch vibe about it & from what I remember, the film is set in a casino & there is an unseen character that may or may not be real, although it's never entirely made clear. 
I think this character goes by a codename like "Cobra" but I can't remember. 
I do recall there being a gold motif throughout the film and an establishing shot that featured a neon light that (to me) looked pretty fake. 
I remember the film being kind of slow and I don't think there was much action.
As far as plot goes, from what I remember the story revolved around the unseen character, with other characters involved in some kind of espionage/conspiracy plot, possibly to overthrow him. I also remember the main character going mad looking at his reflection repeated in an elevator mirror, but can't be sure.

When did you see this movie? Any clue about the release time?

I think the movie you are referring to is Revolver from 2005 by Guy Ritchie and starring Jason Statham and Andre 3000. It's an offbeat crime drama about an ex-con plotting revenge against a casino boss. There's an unseen and feared character called Sam Gold that's probably an alter ego, and this scene of the protagonist going mad in an elevator.

Why the downvote? Revolver sounds like an accurate guess. However, @J.C. I'd suggest adding more detail to your answer (which is probably why the downvote occurred).

It does look like a good guess. I took the liberty of fleshing it out a bit.
